# How to deal with equally growing fact/dimension tables in datawarehouse design?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I have a source data set with:
 1. customer
 2. customer_product_purchase
 3. customer_support_plan_purchase
 4. customer_support_request

All of them have a relationship such that a support request is raised against a plan and product purchase. And that a customer buys a support plan for a product (which the customer also buys).

In order to design a data warehouse schema for this, I was thinking of creating a single fact table, I thought of the following approaches:

A. Having a consolidated fact table with *customer_product_purchase*, *customer_support_plan_purchase* and *customer_support_request* into one as they have a few common attributes (and few uncommon ones which can be kept blank for others). As I believe they are at the same granularity (purchase of product/support plan, raising a request against a support plan). This would mean losing some specific information as to make it generic, like product warranty and support plan validity under the same name **validity**

B. Creating a fact table from *customer_product_purchase* and *customer_support_plan_purchase* which are inherently purchases, and can be kept together with some common and some uncommon attributes. The *customer_support_request* can be treated as separately.

C. Creating a fact table around *customer_support_request* as it ties up to both the other tables, which can be the dimensions. However, this will mean that the dimensions will also grow at the same rate as the fact (**which I have read, is an indicator of bad design**).

So how can I deal with such a situation where the support plan, service request and product purchase can grow by themselves individually, is it best to just keep all of them separate? But because they (all or two of them) have similar granularity, shouldn't they be consolidated?

Comment: I expect you can raise zero or many support requests against a single support plan, so I feel that `support_request` is it's own fact. Is there only ever zero or one support plan per purchase? Can there be a subsequent support plan once the first one has expired? If so, these should also be seperate facts. If you have very few identified repeat customers then yes your customer dim will grow at the same rate as the fact but this is unavoidable

Comment: Fact tables in star schemas should model business processes. I suggest not trying too hard to combine facts unless it makes clear sense to do so. Facts at different detail levels are red flags for not combining.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, you're right, the support plans can be bought subsequently and multiple times against a product. 

Also, from your second comment, I want to know whether the `product sale` and `support plan sale` be considered at the same grain or not? They are still individual transactions (however every support plan references a  product purchase). 
So I was thinking of combining them into one, with some sparse columns (which are non-intersecting between the two tables), with a type columns which specified 'support plan' or 'product' as the purchase type. Think it's a good practice?

Comment: They're not at the same grain because a product sale only happens once. A support plan sale happens 0 or many times for a given product sale. If you put these in the same fact and you have two product sales for the same customer, one with zero support plans and one with three, you end up with five (2+3) records in your fact, and it's difficult to associate the support plans with the sale because they are in different rows. Yes you can tag them with the same invoice number but it just doesn't "feel right" (key design decision making process at work here!)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Great. Thank you so much. If you could please copy your comments as a single answer, I'd mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points from my comments

- Fact tables in star schemas should model business processes.
- I suggest not trying too hard to combine facts unless it makes clear sense to do so. Facts at different detail levels are a strong indicator to not combine

Here some observations about the facts detail levels;

- You can have 0 or many support plans against a single purchase. This is a different level of detail and likely a different fact
- You can raise zero or many support requests against a single support plan. This is a different level of detail and likely a different fact
- If you put support plan and sale in the same fact and you have two product sales for the same customer, one with zero support plans and one with three, you end up with five (2+3) records in your fact, and it's difficult to associate the support plans with the sale because they are in different rows. For example if you want a value ratio of support plan to purchase amount, for a given product group, while not impossible, it's just doesn't "smell" right to have all of these scattered through the same fact
- If you have very few identified repeat customers then yes your customer dim will grow at the same rate as the fact but this is unavoidable and normal

Keep in mind there is never any "best" solution so don't get stuck in analysis paralysis. It's worth modelling in quickly in something like Power BI and throwing some business questions at it. Remember your star schema is about making business questions easier to answer.